# CodeIgniter base_url

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have a problem with codeigniter base_url.
My base_url is `$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])...` (http://test.localhost/)... but when I do an ajax request for example I use `<?= base_url(); ?>installer/test` and the response is "No direct script access allowed".

I try adding to base_url index.php (http://test.localhost/index.php/) and this problem is solved but now when I load an css using base_url like this: <`?= base_url(); ?>assets/css/installer.css` the css is not loading but if I remove index.php the css load correctly but the ajax request response "No direct script access allowed".

Obviously I think that I have a problem with my configuration but I don't find the error. I need that the ajax request and css load under the same `base_url` because the code is big and I can't change all instance of `base_url`.

Comment: `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` is used to make sure that the request has gone through index.php in your root dir. This is for reasons such as making sure that all CI base classes are being loaded and making sure certain vars have been set etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base_url` and `site_url` should be like this:

```
base_url() = http://test.localhost/
site_url() = http://test.localhost/index.php/
```

If you need to load URL resources like CSS, JS, images etc., use `base_url()`, otherwise `site_url()` is better. That means in your ajax request you can set the url like this:

```
var serviceUrl = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>your_controller/your_method";
            var returnResult = $.ajax({
                                            url: serviceUrl,
                                            data: {'id': id, .....},
                                            type: 'post',
                                            dataType: 'json'
                                        });
```

Or you can set the url like this:

```
var serviceUrl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/your_controller/your_method";
            var returnResult = $.ajax({
                                            url: serviceUrl,
                                            data: {'id': id, .....},
                                            type: 'post',
                                            dataType: 'json'
                                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem May be in...

1. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is rarely works in localhost, sometimes it
   failed to detect host route.
2. CSS stylesheet need the pure directory URL, It never include any
   other files with URL like `'localhost/index.php'`

**Try Using...**

1. `$config['base_url'] ='http://test.localhost/';`
2. import css as => `href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/installer.css"`
3. Use Ajax as => `'url' : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/`*your controller path*'

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with this issue spending couple of hours, however solved it in different ways. You can see, I have just created an assets folder outside application folder. Finally I linked my style sheet in the page header section. Folder structure are below images.

[image]
[image]

Before action this you should include **url** helper file either in your controller class method/__constructor files or by in **autoload.php** file. Also change `$config['base_url'] = 'http://yoursiteurl';` in the following file **application/config/config.php**

If you include it in controller class method/__constructor then it look like

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

or If you load in autoload file then it would looks like

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Finally, add your stylesheet file.
You can link a style sheet by different ways, include it in your inside   section

->`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" />`

-> or

```
<?php

    $main = array(
    'href'       => 'assets/css/style.css',
    'rel'        => 'stylesheet',
    'type'       => 'text/css',
    'title'      => 'main stylesheet',
    'media'      => 'all',
    'index_page' => true
    );


echo link_tag($main); ?>
```

-> or

finally I get more reliable code cleaner concept. Just create a config file, named **styles.php** in you **application/config/styles.php** folder.
 Then add some links in **styles.php** file looks like below

```
<?php
 $config['style'] = array(
    'main' => array(
        'href'       => 'assets/css/style.css',
        'rel'        => 'stylesheet',
        'type'       => 'text/css',
        'title'      => 'main stylesheet',
        'media'      => 'all',
        'index_page' => true
    )
 );

?>
```

call/add this config to your controller class method looks like below

```
$this->config->load('styles');
$data['style'] = $this->config->config['style'];
```

Pass this data in your header template looks like below.

```
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
```

And finally add or  link your css file looks like below.

```
<?php echo link_tag($style['main']); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

`base_url` is used to access image JS, files, and CSS and site URL is for accessing controller's function. In `base_url` `index.php` is not present but in `site_url` `index.php` press end to define `base_url` like this:

```
$config['base_url'] =  http://project_name/assets/file_name;
$config['site_url'] = http://project_name/controller/function;
```

Comment: @AbdulSalam please stop code-tagging the word "URL". It is not code and should not be tagged as such.